# can't send html form email in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to send an email to customers with html form.

here is the controller file.

```
$email = 'jc2332@gmail.com';

$title = 'Introducing our new product!';

$msg = $this->load->view('admin/email_new_version', '', true);

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('cs@example.com', 'company');
$this->email->to($email); 

$this->email->subject($title);
$this->email->message($msg);    

$this->email->send();
```

It looks fine for me, but html doesn't work when I receive the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this configuration and try to initialize the email library in a separated command:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. What do you mean when you say "html doesn't work when I receive the mail"? What kind of environment do you host it on?

Let's try simple debugging:

1) Check if the template is being loaded:

```
echo $this->load->view('admin/email_new_version', '', true);
die();
```

2) [Validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML.

3) Try setting different values in `crlf`, `newline` and `charset` preferences.

Answer (score 1):

1. go system/libraries/email.php
2. check $mailtype vairable value
3. set $mailtype='html'

Answer (score 0):

I think main area to focus on is whether or not you are using a local setup like wamp/lamp or any other local server installation where you are using a regular adsl connection with your ports not serving outside your lan.

You need to host your project in a hosting provider or open your ports to be able to serve to internet (the latter is not recommended without taking security precautions and also without having a mail server running this should not work) in order for email->send() function to work properly